# Gmaps4jsf marker cluster

Tags: google-maps, jsf-1.2

I am working on google map project.i want to show many marker using marker cluster tag.
But i dont know how to provide lat and long to marker cluster tag using java code.please anybody have such code in java then let me know.

Technologies i am using are

- JSF
- gmaps4jsf
- java

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check the examples of GMaps4JSF:
http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/home.jsf

As you see the markerCluster component:

```
<pre>
<m:markerCluster>
    <m:marker address="Moncloa, Madrid" />
    <m:marker address="Paris, France" />
    <m:marker address="Cairo, Egypt" />
</m:markerCluster>
</pre>
```

The marker component can have the latitude and longitude as attributes instead of the address attribute as shown here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/wiki/markerComponent

Hazem Saleh
GMaps4JSF Founder